# owning sibling fields and lifetime

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store tools in tool belts and keep tool belts in a toolbox. I'm also trying to index the tools in the toolbox itself to quickly grab them. This is just an abstraction since there are no tools, etc. in my project.

When storing tools in a tool belt, I get back an intrusive reference (cursor) to the tool. I'm trying to store this reference in the tool box index but this doesn't seem to work!

This seems to be a case of referencing a sibling field.

Run `cargo init --bin toolbox`, add `intrusive-collections = "0.3"` under dependencies and then replace `main.rs` with the code below.

You should get this error when you run it:

```
Compiling toolbox v0.1.0 (file:///Users/joelr/Work/rust/node)
src/main.rs:67:31: 67:36 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
src/main.rs:67         let belt = self.belts.entry(belt_id).or_insert_with(|| Belt::new());
                                             ^~~~~
src/main.rs:65:5: 71:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn add(&'a mut self, belt_id: u64, tool_id: u64, size: u64)
src/main.rs:65     fn add<'b>(&'b mut self, belt_id: u64, tool_id: u64, size: u64) {
```

Can I have my cake and eat it too?

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate intrusive_collections;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::convert::{AsRef, AsMut};
use intrusive_collections::{IntrusiveRef, LinkedList, LinkedListLink, linked_list};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tool {
    id: u64,
    size: u64,
    link: LinkedListLink,
}

impl Tool {
    fn new(id: u64, size: u64) -> Self {
        Tool {
            id: id,
            size: size,
            link: LinkedListLink::new(),
        }
    }
}

intrusive_adaptor!(ToolAdaptor = Tool { link: LinkedListLink });

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Belt {
    total_size: u64,
    tools: LinkedList<ToolAdaptor>,
}

impl Belt {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Belt {
            total_size: 0,
            tools: LinkedList::new(ToolAdaptor),
        }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, tool: Tool) -> CursorMut {
        let r = IntrusiveRef::from_box(Box::new(tool));
        self.tools.push_back(r);
        self.tools.back_mut()
    }
}

type CursorMut<'a> = linked_list::CursorMut<'a, ToolAdaptor>;
type Belts = HashMap<u64, Belt>;
type Tools<'a> = HashMap<u64, CursorMut<'a>>;

struct ToolBox<'a> {
    tools: Tools<'a>,
    belts: Belts,
}

impl<'a> ToolBox<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        ToolBox {
            tools: HashMap::new(),
            belts: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add<'b>(&'b mut self, belt_id: u64, tool_id: u64, size: u64) {
        let tool = Tool::new(tool_id, size);
        let belt = self.belts.entry(belt_id).or_insert_with(|| Belt::new());
        let cursor = belt.add(tool);
        self.tools.insert(tool_id, cursor);
        ()
    }

    fn belts(&self) -> &Belts {
        &self.belts
    }
}

impl<'a> AsRef<ToolBox<'a>> for ToolBox<'a> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Self {
        self
    }
}

impl<'a> AsMut<ToolBox<'a>> for ToolBox<'a> {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut toolbox = ToolBox::new();
    toolbox.add(1, 1, 1);
    println!("ToolBox belts = {:?}", toolbox.as_ref().belts())
}
```

Comment: Would you kindly [edit] your question to explain why *this* question is different from the [62 other questions with the same error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+borrow+as+immutable+because+it+is+also+borrowed+as+mutable+is%3Aquestion)?

Comment: There's also [15 questions for the second error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+infer+an+appropriate+lifetime+for+autoref+due+to+conflicting+requirements+is%3Aquestion). I assume that you are also aware of all of those?

Comment: Most definitely. Browsed through, thought about it. Spent a few days on this issue too. Edited the question to narrow it down to the second issue.

Comment: *Most definitely. Browsed through, thought about it. Spent a few days on this issue too.* **None** of that is evident in the question. [SO expects a lot of evidence of the effort you have put in](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/155423), especially for problems that are frequently answered (as these two are). Since you have read and understand ~80 related questions, you should be able to elaborate on what you don't understand from them. Otherwise the answer you get here may be a duplicate of an existing answer and you will be no better off and the answerer will have wasted their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be made to work as I have written it above. For example, it would be possible to delete items from the linked list in the `ToolBelt` which would invalidate the `Tool` references stored in the `ToolBox`.

I ended up rewriting the code using a [linked hash map](https://github.com/contain-rs/linked-hash-map). It keeps items in order of insertion *and* lets me delete them by key.